# callback functionality needed

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to construct a JavaScript function that accepts a transition function as one of its parameters.  Keep in mind that this transition function is user built so it will have a variety of syntax, but the goal of this function is to transition the webpage from one style to another.

For example, the page might currently have a vertical three column layout and calling this transition function might change it into a horizontal two column layout.

What I need is some type of callback or wait/sleep function until the transition is complete (which is designated by the presence of a particular form object).  I've been trying to use eval(), but have read several many posts on not using this.  Below is an example of the code I'm looking for - no jquery or other framework please.

```
// MAKE ANY WEBPAGE TRANSITIONS
if (transition != '') {
    eval(transition, callback) {
        success: alert('done with the transition eval call');
    }
}
```

Comment: I've no idea why you are trying to use `eval`. It doesn't have any way to do what your asking, and your syntax just isn't JavaScript.

Comment: It's not meant to be real JS, just an idea of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The transition function has to be designed to accept a callback in the first place.

```
function transition(callback) {
    // Do stuff
    callback();
}

transition(function () { alert("end of transition"); });
```

There is no generic way to detect when a function which performs asynchronous actions (such as Ajax or `setTimeout` calls) has finished. The function itself has to provide a way.